# Pull data from Active Directory with Python, Golang or Ruby on rails

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I would like to make a web application which can pull data from Active Directory. At my work many developers recommend me to learn C# or Java mostly because they are using it. Is it possible to achieve it with other programming languages like Python, Ruby or Go? What would you recommend? The application I would like to create need to have access to every singel user and computer attribute available in Active Directory, not only simple data like username or email address. The list of all AD attributes is in the link below.
http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm

Comment: I would recommend picking one of those languages and starting to research how to access the data you want from AD using it. This is far too broad for SO as posed.

Comment: Active Directory servers speak the LDAP protocol, so any programming language whose ecosystem has a package implementing support for TCP/IP networking and LDAP above it would fit the bill. Personally, I had first-hand experience querying an AD forest run by a bunch of w2k3r2 servers using https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/ldap.v2 — it worked just OK.

Comment: See also: https://godoc.org/?q=ldap

Comment: Oh, and note that [your question is off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); so I voted to close it.